# Is there a program out there that looks at LESS and PHP/HTML files and cuts out CSS that isn't used

Tags: php, html, css, less

With the advent of several CSS bootstraps and boilerplates is there not a program what will grab all the tags in a certain directory (element, class, id) and strip everything that isn't used from a less file and compiles to a CSS file? would that not save a good amount of space? Let me know if you know of any.

EDIT: I'm not talking about running it live or anything. more for those of us who pre-compile

Comment: But, how can it know if, at anytime by Javascript/jQuery you'll not be manipulating the DOM?

Comment: Yea, I agree I would never trust such a program.  It would have no way to know if a string constant in Javascript referred to a CSS selector.

Comment: it looks for id and class tags in javascript files as well. It's totally doable I'm just wondering if there is one out there already.

EDIT: if it sees something that looks like a class or id in any string constants in the javascript it cross-references the LESS file to see if there are any rules for it. if there are it includes it if not it doesn't have to worry about it.

Comment: There have been a couple of attempts at this sort of thing. They work ok for limited, static sites, but as the others have said it's totally not doable for anything more complex

Comment: any idea where I can find these attempts?

Comment: Its not doable John, what if I build a string to create a css class name that I then apply to a DOM element in javascript code.  There is no way you can know if the class will be used unless you run the code.  Sometimes you still need the human being!

Comment: I still think that can be worked with... I'll have to see about trying to make one myself then I suppose. Thanks everyone for the info.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know of any but what i do is keep things organized in separate files. That way i can roll up only whats needed for a particular view. I tend not to get all too specific though so im sure there are unused rules on any given page. A basic example of what i might have is:

base.less

```
// this is the sheet for the global layout and is needed for every page

@import "reset.less";
@import "util.less"; // these are all mixins for grids, clearfix, gradients, etc..
@import "typography.less"; // fontface, basic typo grid
@import "brand.less"; //mixins for colors, brand specific sprites, etc..
@import "components.less"; // these are rules for components that might be used anywhere

/* rules for global layout and default element styles follow */
```

viewname.less

```
// this is the view/page specific sheet
@import "util.less"; // these are all mixins for grids, clearfix, gradients, etc..
@import "typography.less"; // fontface, basic typo grid
@import "brand.less"; //mixins for colors, brand specific sprites, etc..
@import "viewname.components.less"; // set of component styles used only for this view
```

viewname.components.less

```
// this is a "roll up" sheet that imports different componets used in this specific view
// this way i can each component separate but still use them in different views.
@import "somewidget.component.less";
@import "someotherwidget.component.less";
```

So then basically i only ever include 2 stylesheets the base and the one for the view. Everything gets compiled and minified on the server side before delivery